# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity'

Tags: c#, linq, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to parse a dynamic Expression string using Linq

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var e = Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { x }, null, "x.Id > 1");

var compiledDelegate = exp.Compile();

var values = new List<T>
{
    new T
    {
        Id = 1
    },
    new T
    {
        Id = 2
    }
};

var result = values.Where((Func<T, bool>)compiledDelegate);
```

When trying to execute the `ParseLambda` line, the code throws the below exception

[image]

I am using net standard 2.0 and Visual Studio 15.3.5.

I am pulling the below two packages with all the necessary ASP.NET core stuff.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Have you referenced System.Data.Entity explicitly in your project? It's not listed as a package reference

Comment: There are no `System.Data` or `System.Data.Entity` in NuGet. There is `System.Data.Common` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

With more googling I found that System.Data is not yet ported (if it will ever be) to .net standard 2.0 APIs so `System.Linq.Dynamic` was actually not fully compatible with .net standard 2.0.

[image]

Instead I found another port of the same assembly `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` which did the job.

[image]